# Multiple TD after some TD move to new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am generating a table dynamically and adding new TR and TD to it dynamically in the following manner.

```
$('#tableId').append('<tr><th colspan="2"></th>');
```

The above code is called only once in my code.

Then I am adding TD to it in the following manner:

```
var tempurl = 'http://google.com';
$('<td>').appendTo($('#tableId')).html("<a href='"+tempurl+"'>"+tempurl+"</a>");
```

The problem that I am facing is, all TD are getting aligned in one row(in the same line only) and my page width get increased by many times.

I tried adding css to table so that if table size exceed TD should go to next line:

```
max-width: 90%;
display: block;
```

and

```
display: inline;
```

but it is not working out for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please code a correct static HTML table and then use this code to generate dynamically a still correct table.

Here's an example of such a table:

```
<table>
    <caption>Google results</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Title and link</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="http://domain.com/1">Stack Overflow</a>
            </td>
            <td>Stack Overflow is a website (...)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="http://domain.com/2">Stack Exchange</a>
            </td>
            <td>Stack Exchange is a website (...)</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

- no need for a header cell spanning all rows: you probably intend it as a caption
- in a vertical table, you should have a header cell (`th`) on top of each column, in `thead` element (I added `scope="col"` attribute for accessibility reasons. It'd be `row` if header cells were on left of each row. Don't use `scope` if you've `colspan` or `rowspan` somewhere)
- in `tbody` element, one row (`tr`) per actual row
- in each row, as many `td` elements as there are header cells (except if there are some `colspan` or `rowspan`)

EDIT: why do you have 2 different `id`? Confusing.

Comment: `id` is same on `appendTo` method as well, that was my mistake I just corrected in my question.
I have written a correct code to generate a table, my only concern is its `css` all TD as getting arranged in one row.

Comment: Do you have as closing `</tr>` as needed? Did you inspect HTML code in Firebug or DevTools?

Comment: yup I have a closing `</tr>` tag, I have check my code all `tags` are properly generated, but I am getting all `<td>` tag in one row, because of that my page width is getting increased by many times.